# how can i recognize in pc that which domain name should be linked to which folder

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I want to forward different domain names to single IP Address (local for testing), but how can i recognize in pc that which domain name should be linked to which folder?

for example, in windows host file, I wrote

```
127.0.0.1       abc.com
127.0.0.1       test.abc.com
127.0.0.1       test1.abc.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being found within the same `VirtualHost` section binds the `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` directives together.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www1.example.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/web/www1
</VirtuaHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www2.example.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/web/www2
</VirtuaHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to the root configuration directory and run this command

`grep -Ri www.domain.tld .` (your domain name)
or

`grep -ri "VirtualHost" /`    (your specific virtualhost to find its directiory)

and it will lead you to the folder...